# Comparing a DateTime Value to any value on a list of DateTimes in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, winforms

I have an Appointment Scheduling Application where you set an Appointment Time and when you set that time, I want to check and see if their appointment is overlapping any other Appointment times and if So then I want to prevent them from scheduling the appointment.
I have 2 lists containing the appointment start and End Times:

```
public List<DateTime> AppointmentStartTimes = new List<DateTime>();
public List<DateTime> AppointmentEndTimes = new List<DateTime>();
```

I want them to not be able to schedule an appointment if the start time is in between any of the values on either of these lists, How would I compare the time to the values on both lists thanks?

Comment: Can you explain a little more. How do you connect start time and end time? by index of the list?

Comment: they are separate times in separate fields stored in a MySQL Database, I have a Windows Form Application has 2 DateTimePickers that allow you to select your starting time and date and when they click the add appointment button I want to compare the values of the start time to see if that start time they selected is anywhere on the AppointmentStartTimes list.

Comment: So, you want to check if the value already exists?

Comment: Yes I want to check and see if the start time is between Any of the times on the StartTimes List and any of the values on the EndTimes List.

Comment: So `AppointmentStartTimes[0]` and `AppointmentEndTimes[0]` describe _one_ appointment and then `AppointmentStartTimes[1]` and `AppointmentEndTimes[1]` describe another? Why not have an `Appointment` class with start and end property and then have only _one_ list? -- But basically, you want for each index: `var start = AppointmentStartTimes[index]; var end = AppointmentEndTimes[index]; if ((start <= newStart && end >= newStart) || (start <= newEnd && end >= newEnd)) { [handle overlap] } else { [handle not an overlap for THIS index] }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using two lists, a cleaner / more extensible approach would be to create an `Appointment` class:

```
class Appointment
{
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    public bool ConflictsWith(Appointment proposed)
    {
        return StartTime < proposed.EndTime && proposed.StartTime < EndTime;
    }
}
```

Then you can have a single list of appointments:

```
public List<Appointment> Appointments = new List<Appointment>();
```

And you can check for conflicts as so:

```
Appointment proposed = //...
bool conflicts = Appointments.Any(appointment => appointment.ConflictsWith(proposed));
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to create a class Appointment, which has a.o. a TimeFrame. A TimeFrame has a StartTime / EndTime / Duration:

```
interface ITimeFrame
{
    DateTime StartTime {get;}
    DateTime EndTime {get;}
    TimeSpan Duration {get;}
}
```

Possible implementations:

```
class TimeFrame : ITimeFrame
{
    public DateTime StartTime {get; set;}
    public DateTime EndTime {get; set;}
    public TimeSpan Duration => EndTime - StartTime;
}
```

But you could also choose for an Implementation where the EndTime => StartTime + Duration

```
interface AppointMent
{
    int Id {get; }
    IReadOnlyCollection<Person> Attendees {get;}

    ITimeFrame TimeFrame {get; }
}
```

You want to know whether two Appointment overlap. I create it as extension methods of ITimeFrame and IAppointment:

```
public static bool Overlaps(this ITimeFrame timeFrameA, ITimeFrame timeFrameB)
{
    // assuming startTime of a TimeFrame is always smaller than EndTime
    // there is an overlap if
    // frameA starts before frameB ends AND frameA ends after frameB starts
    return timeFrameA.StartTime < timeFrameB.EndTime
        && timeFrameA.EndTime > timeFrame.StartTime;
}

public static bool Overlaps(this IAppointment appointmentA, IAppontment appointmentB)
{
    return appointmentA.TimeFrame.Overlaps(appointmentB.TimeFrame);
}
```

Usage:

```
IAppointment a = ...
IAppointment b = ...
bool overlaps = a.Overlaps(b);
```

For LINQ we do the same with sequences:

```
public static bool Overlaps(
    this IEnumerable<IAppointment> appointments,
    IAppointment otherAppointment)
{
    return appointments.Where(appointment => appointment.Overlaps(otherAppointment)).Any();
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<IAppointment> existingAppointment = ...
IAppointment requestedAppointment = ...

var hasOverlappingAppointments = existingAppointment
    .Overlaps(requestedAppointment)
    .Any();
if (hasOverlappingAppointments)
{
    WriteMessage("Can't make this appointment, it overlaps with existing appointments");
}
else
{
    AcceptAppointment(requestedAppointment);
}
```